# How do I remove a specific character if and only if it repeats consecutively using Python?

Tags: python, string

I have provided an elaborate version of my question below:

Consider the string `"apples----are-the--best---fruits"` I want to remove all `'-'`s only if they repeat consecutively. So my output should be "apples-are-the-best-fruits".

How can I accomplish this? Thanks.

Comment: There are many ways to achieve this. Did you try something? What exactly did you struggle with?

Answer (score 1):

Check if this helps -

```
'-'.join([i for i in x.split("-") if i])
```

Where `x` is your `string`

Comment: strings of lenght 0 are falsy anyway. `if i` is sufficient

Answer (score 0):

Different ways to reach your goal. Using string.replace is the worst one, because lots of intermediate strings will be created (they are immutable) and discarded.

```
# string replace - inefficient due to lots of strings created
orgstring = "apples----are-the--best---fruits"

mystring =  orgstring 
while '--' in mystring: 
    mystring = mystring.replace('--','-')
print (mystring)
```

Better would be either of these ways: use a list to collect all chars you need or use regex to solve it:

```
orgstring = "apples----are-the--best---fruits"

# list iterating appending unless its a duplicate -
mystring = ""
mylist = []
for c in orgstring:
    if not mylist or mylist[-1] != '-' or c != '-':
        mylist.append(c)

mystring = ''.join(mylist)
print(mystring)

# regex replacement of more then 1 - by only 1 -
import re
mystring = ""
mystring = re.sub("-+","-",orgstring)
print(mystring)
```

Output:

```
apples-are-the-best-fruits
apples-are-the-best-fruits
apples-are-the-best-fruits
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it would be to iterate over the input string and check for each character `-` if it's consecutive to another character `-` using a counter as follows:

```
def convertString(inString):
    newString = []
    counter = 0

    for letter in inString:
        if letter == '-':
            if counter > 0:
                continue
            else:
                newString.append(letter)
                counter = counter + 1
        else:
            newString.append(letter)
            counter = 0

    return "".join(newString)

inString = "apples----are-the--best---fruits"
newString = convertString(inString)
print(newString)
```

Output:

```
apples-are-the-best-fruits
```